# version_conflict_engine_exception with multiple _update_by_query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have situation where i am getting `version_conflict_engine_exception`. I have daemon which continuously pushing data for update to elasticsearch. I am using `_updat_by_query`. Here is the sample call:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_update_by_query?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
   "query":{
      "term":{
         "userid":1234
      }
   },
   "script":{
      "lang":"painless",
      "inline":"if (ctx._source.containsKey(\"newfield\")) {ctx._source.newfiled.add(params.value)} else {ctx._source.newfield = [params.value]}",
      "params":{
         "value":{"new":"value"}
      }
   }
}'
```

Whenever i have same userid (on `query.terms`), there is multiple update query hits one after another and it gives me error `version_conflict_engine_exception` . I know its because of version conflicting but how we can overcome from this where i have frequently update queries. I also not finding any `bulk` option for `_update_by_query`. I am getting following error:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 1,
    "updated": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "batches": 1,
    "version_conflicts": 1,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
    },
    "throttled_millis": 0,
    "requests_per_second": -1.0,
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures": [{
        "index": "my_index",
        "type": "my_type",
        "id": "Gc-_SWIBUzg1_4kxJ5uD",
        "cause": {
            "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
            "reason": "[logs][Gc-_SWIBUzg1_4kxJ5uD]: version conflict, current version [2] is different than the one provided [1]",
            "index_uuid": "dbtt5uS9R3ClcPt6Oar1MQ",
            "shard": "3",
            "index": "my_index"
        },
        "status": 409
    }]
}
```

Comment: Use conflicts=proceed parameter in the query string

Comment: i am already using. Havent mention in sample call. Not helped

Comment: Can you post the complete error msg and the trace, may be a screenshot

Comment: @sramalingam24 i edited post with error. Please check it thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13619 maybe this can help

Comment: @sramalingam24 I already went through this link . I think it's using only single update query. The `retry_on_conflict` can be use with update query. But I want to know how we can use this with `update_by_query`?

Comment: Seems like your only option is to keep rerunning the query with conflicts=proceed& refresh=wait_for as suggested here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22723

Comment: @sramalingam24 thats cool its fix my problem. I am passing refresh=true. Thanks for the help. You can put in answer with more explanation so that all can be know who is facing such issue.

Comment: cool that worked out. Added it as an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Currently this is the expected behavior in Elasticsearch. You can try to workaround this by using the conflicts and refresh parameters.

You can use

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed&refresh=wait_for'
```

as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22723#issuecomment-274156818). Hope that helps!

Comment: [as stated here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/docs-update-by-query.html) the Update By Query API doesn't support wait_for for the refresh parameter